# How do we create a trackbar in Open CV so that I can use it to skip to specific section of the video?

Tags: python, opencv

I have to skip to a specific section of a video using Open CV - Python, like a  track bar that we usually see in a normal video player. How do I create such trackbar that can be used to skip to a specific section of a video?

And also how do we increase the framerate of a video so that it looks like the loaded video is fast forwarded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code below does what you want.  It adds 2 trackbars to the video display window, that control the next frame and the playback speed.
When the video is opened first the total number of frames is retrieved. This is used to set the max of the 'Frame' trackbar. When you move the slider on that trackbar, a function is called that sets the variable for the next frame to be read.
The 'Speed' trackbar sets the wait time in between frames, it is scaled in milliseconds. That wait time is the time the frame is displayed and user input can be processed. That means that when you set it lower, the wait time is shorter, so the video moves faster. It starts at 50, so that is about 1000/50=20 fps. Note however that the actual speed is also affected by the code that runs in the while loop, this is added to the wait time. For example, when I ran a video at wait time 1 ms, the actual time averaged at 6 ms.
To get the most speed, remove the line of code that updates the 'Frame' slider position.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# function called by trackbar, sets the next frame to be read
def getFrame(frame_nr):
    global video
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_nr)

#  function called by trackbar, sets the speed of playback
def setSpeed(val):
    global playSpeed
    playSpeed = max(val,1)

# open video
video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.webm")
# get total number of frames
nr_of_frames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
# create display window
cv2.namedWindow("Video")
# set wait for each frame, determines playbackspeed
playSpeed = 50
# add trackbar
cv2.createTrackbar("Frame", "Video", 0,nr_of_frames,getFrame)
cv2.createTrackbar("Speed", "Video", playSpeed,100,setSpeed)

# main loop
while 1:
    # Get the next videoframe
    ret, frame = video.read()

    # show frame, break the loop if no frame is found
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
        # update slider position on trackbar
        # NOTE: this is an expensive operation, remove to greatly increase max playback speed
        cv2.setTrackbarPos("Frame","Video", int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)))
    else:
        break

    # display frame for 'playSpeed' ms, detect key input
    key = cv2.waitKey(playSpeed)

    # stop playback when q is pressed
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

# release resources
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement the same above trackbar on Tkinter?

Comment: Much the same way, but instead use the trackbar of tkinter to call the above functions. It is more of a hassle to display the video though, so I would advice against it if not absolutely necessary. You can also look into [cvui](https://pypi.org/project/cvui/) to create a GUI, which is specifically for openCV.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to read all the images into a list (part 1). After the video has been converted to a list of images, use the track bar to select the desired location in the list (part 2).

Keep the memory profiler open when running this script.

```
import cv2
frames = []
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Read images into list (part 1)
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    frames.append(img)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k ==27: break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(len(frames))

# Setup trackbars
def nothing(arg): pass
cv2.namedWindow('img')
cv2.createTrackbar('frame_number', 'img', 0,len(frames), nothing)

# Show the image selected by the trackbar (part 2)
while True:
    frame_number = cv2.getTrackbarPos('frame_number', 'img')
    print(frame_number)
    img = frames[frame_number]
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k ==27: break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```